# How to sync SQL Server database with Amazon RDS SQL Server database?

Tags: sql-server, database, amazon-web-services, synchronization, rds

I have a SQL Server database on one of my local servers and I need to create an image of it on RDS and enable synching between the two databases.

Is that possible? Anybody who can help?

Answer (score 0):

Replication is the obvious answer, but unfortunately but SQL Server on RDS does not support it.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_SQLServer.html

(about 1/3 the way down the page).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Database Migration Service](https://aws.amazon.com/dms/) for this now. We've been using it successfully for close to a year.

We're syncing from RDS to RDS though. On-prem to RDS is a bit more difficult as you need to setup replication where as that's not required when the source is RDS.